# Do apksigner supports timestamp server argument?

Tags: jarsigner, apksigner

**[jarsigner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html)** allows to provide the timestamp server as an argument (*-tsa*) but **[apksigner](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html)** timestamp server argument seems to be missing.

1. apksigner don't support timestamp server argument?
2. apksigner don't need timestamp server argument?

Answer (score 0):

`apksigner` does not support timestamping because Android does not care about timestamps in APKs.